# Way to remove alpha component on tvOS UITableView highlight?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tvos

Is there any way at all to remove the alpha selection style of a UITableView. I want to keep the enlargement of the cell, but the colour change makes the text contained in the cell unreadable. I can remove the selection altogether by using `self.focusStyle = .custom`
 on the cell, but that also removes the enlargment[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to custom everything:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UITableViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let prevIndexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath, let prevCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: prevIndexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            prevCell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }
    }

    if let nextIndexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath, let nextCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: nextIndexPath) {
        let bg: UIView = UIView(frame: nextCell.bounds)
        bg.backgroundColor = .blue
        nextCell.selectedBackgroundView = bg
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            nextCell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
        }
    }
}
```